# $\partial \bar\partial$-lemma for difference of probability measures

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-geometry

Let $X$ be a complex Kahler manifold of dimension $k$. For a smooth $(k,k)$form $\omega$, it is for sure $\partial$ and $\bar\partial$-closed since it is of top degree. Assume that $\omega$ is a difference of two probability measures.

Could we prove that $\omega$ is further $\partial$ or $\bar\partial$-exact? If not, when could we apply the $\partial \bar\partial$-lemma to a smooth form $\omega$ of top degree?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that what you mean by "difference of two probability measures" is that $\omega = \alpha - \beta$ with $\alpha$ and $\beta$ real non-negative $(n,n)$ forms such that $\int_X \alpha = \int_X \beta = 1$. In this case, $\int_X \omega = 0$.

The $\partial\overline{\partial}$-lemma tells you that if $\omega = d\gamma$ for $\gamma$ a $2n - 1$ form, then $\omega = i\partial\overline{\partial}\delta$ with $\delta$ some real $(n - 1,n - 1)$ form. In other words, $d$-closed implies $\partial\overline{\partial}$-closed.

And by Hodge duality, the natural pairing $H^{n,n}(X,\mathbb{R}) \times H^0(X,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ is non degenerate hence $\dim(H^{n,n}(X,\mathbb{R})) = 1$ (when the manifold is connected, else it doesn't work). Moreover, by Stokes' theorem, if $\alpha$ is $d$-closed, then $\int_X \alpha = 0$. By equality of the dimensions, the reciprocal holds. In other words, $\omega$ is $d$-closed, thus $\partial\overline{\partial}$-closed.

In particular, it is $\partial$- and $\overline{\partial}$-closed.

Comment: Good! Your answer clarifies my statement.